# Order of autocomplete suggestions in PHP Intelephense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

How can I specify the order of autocomplete suggestions provided by [Intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/intelephense) extension for VS Code?

In particular, I would like to push all the classes located in `vendor` directory down the list. In other words, I would like classes specific to my app to appear first in the list.

I looked into the settings options of this package, but didn't find anything that would allow me to modify the order of autocomplete options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Though, for this particular case it would be possible using the `sortText` property. In general, VSCode extensions have limited ability to influence suggestion sorting via `sortText` and `preselect` properties of the `CompletionItem`. VSCode has it's own ranking algorithm that dominates suggestion order.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that it would work because `vendor` would be at the bottom of the list sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Correct, sortText could be modified to be sorted last alphabetically

Comment: Just realized that you're the extension author - I think you should mention it in the answer, so it's easier for people to know it comes from the 'source' ;) By the way: are you planning to add such feature (maybe as a config option)? Or would you rather have someone PR it?

Comment: I'm planning on adding it to act as a tiebreaker when suggestions are ranked the same by the matched text